# How to fetch text file to array in perl

Tags: perl

I have a text file without header as bellow format:

```
2017-03-13 00,r1,306011,306011,OK,Allgood.
2017-03-13 01,r2,20369,20369,OK,Allgood.
2017-03-13 02,r3,283751,283751,OK,Allgood.
2017-03-13 03,r4,53017,53017,OK,Allgood.
```

How to fetch this file to array in perl ? I want to print out them with the looping.

```
my $s_size = scalar(@array);
for(my $i=1; $i<=$s_size;$i++)
{
    print ("$array[$i][0]\n");
    print ("$array[$i][1]\n");
}
```

The expected result:

```
2017-03-13 00
2017-03-13 01
2017-03-13 02
2017-03-13 03
r1
r2
r3
r4
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? StackOverflow is not a "write my code for me" service.

Answer (score 2):

One of more possible solutions could be

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

my @lines;
while(<>) {
    chomp;
    push @lines, [split /\s*,\s*/];
}
say $_->[0] for @lines;
say $_->[1] for @lines;
```

output

```
2017-03-13 00
2017-03-13 01
2017-03-13 02
2017-03-13 03
r1
r2
r3
r4
```

As @Sobrique and also @BOC said, you can use

```
my @lines = map { chomp; [split /,/] } <>;
say $_->[0] for @lines;
say $_->[1] for @lines;
```

and finally by

- using a the [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) module
- having a `$filename`

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $filename = "xd.csv";

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({auto_diag => 1, binary => 1});

open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "$filename: $!";
my $lines = $csv->getline_all($fh); #note the arrayref
close($fh);

say $_->[0] for @$lines;
say $_->[1] for @$lines;
```

Comment: I think if all I'm doing is a chomp and push, I'd consider using `map` instead.  `my @lines = map { chomp; [split /,/] } <>;`

Comment: Given the input data - `\s*` in the split is also redundant, as there's no whitespace on either side of the commas.

Comment: @Sobrique for the given data the `\s*` doesn't hurts. In a case, where are spaces around commas, usually (at least me), want data with trimmed spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some mistakes in the expected result and the printing loop. Here is how I would do it:

```
my $filename='/path/test.txt';
open (my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
my @array;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    push @array, [split ',', $line];
}

my $s_size = scalar(@array);
for(my $i=0; $i<$s_size;$i++)
{
print ("$array[$i][0]\n");
print ("$array[$i][1]\n");
}
```

the result is:

```
2017-03-13 00
r1
2017-03-13 01
r2
2017-03-13 02
r3
2017-03-13 03
r4
```

We can also do it in one line if you like:

```
my @array = map {chomp; [split ',']} <>;
```

Comment: `my $filename='/path/test.txt';`

Where is the place should i put `$filename` ?

Comment: as a style point - I'd recommend using `/,/` in split, instead of a quote, because that way it's entirely clear that it's using a regex rather than a 'plain string'.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's some mix-up in what you request. It seems your expected output doesn't match in any way the output your code is intended to give. If we keep to the code, this will give you your output (given this filename):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = '/path/to/file';
open my $FILE, '<', $filename or die $!;

while(my $line = <$FILE>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @array = split(/,/, $line);
    print "$array[0]\n";
    print "$array[1]\n";
}
close $FILE;
```

This simplifies your code. If you want it to be as your expected output, simply `push @array2, $array[1]` (here, `@array2` is a new array you need to declare) and print it after the `while` loop.